# Why do I have a massive difference in per partition restore point size?

Tags: windows, system-restore

Why is it that restore points on `E:` are only 6MB, whereas restore points on `C:` are 8GB?

Comment: It’s quite simple: Restore points grow in size as files are _modified_ or _deleted_. Adding files has almost no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Restore points are used to revert system changes *on the drive that the restore point is on*.

The reason for having a smaller restore point on one drive compared to another is because that drive will have less changes, such as programs installed, that can have their changes reverted or simply less changes happened on that drive.

Restore points never contain information from another drive.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-system-restore-a9d1b33f-1df9-e0f2-8aa3-d904cd940ee4): "System Restore takes a 'snapshot' of the some system files and the Windows registry and saves them as Restore Points". I don't see the mention of a disk here. Most likely the post itself is wrong.

Comment: @harrymc System Restore points are per partition and stored within the directory `System Volume Information` in the root of the respecitive partition: `SystemPropertiesAdvanced` → _System Protection_ → _Protection Settings_ → Select partition → _Configure..._

Comment: @harrymc Restore Points use the [Volume Shadow Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) and in order for it to be performant during updates and upgrades you want to do a minimal amount of work. That means *not* copying an entire file of potentially huge size and instead simply moving/renaming it when changes happen. Copying an entire 2GB program across disks when it is updated would make updates far less appealing when the system could "simply" rename and reallocate with some book-keeping for system restore backups. It would also make for much weirder disk space issues.

Comment: @JW0914: No, it's per Windows installation. You may configure the storage location for restore points, replacing/adding-to the one that was used before, but as it contains Windows information all coming from the one system disk, all restore points should have similar size in all locations. They are not scattered in pieces. The poster is comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: @harrymc Nope, system restore protection is configured *per disk* [https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoUoq.png] and space allocated is also configured *per disk* [https://i.stack.imgur.com/4be1Z.png] It even says "Create a restore point right now **for the drives that have system protection turned on**"

Comment: @harrymc While reviewing [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service) doesn't provide a definitive answer to this scenario, simply enabling System Restore on multiple partitions, taking a snapshot, and comparing size differentials is the easiest method to see your perspective is factually inaccurate: [Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/0OMmJAh) _(Control group: `C:`: 26.37GB; `M:`: 0MB; `D:`: 0MB | Test: `C:` 26.4GB; `M:` 2.11MB; `D:` 0MB| Test2: `C:` 26.46GB; `M:` 6.53MB; `D:` 7.27MB)_

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Non-`C:` VSS restore points should be accessible across Windows OSes since each partition is GUID independent and VSS backups are matched to the GUID of the respective partition, which is also stored in the `System Volume Information` directory.

Comment: There's a confusion here between VSS and System Restore. But I give up.

Comment: System Restore **uses** VSS, there is no confusion.

Comment: VSS *can* be used by other applications, such as Windows Backup, to copy data to other drives but System Restore works on a *per drive* basis to protect system files *on that drive*.

Comment: @harrymc System Restore points are created via VSS, as it's the only way to take a differential backup in Windows while booted to the OS without restore point data corruption from in-use system files. Your perspective has a fundamental misunderstanding and perhaps is conflating different backup solutions, as System Restore and it's restore points has used VSS since at least Windows 7, if not earlier. I uploaded the screenshots in my previous comment to show restore points are per partition by comparing the restore point sizes of three different partitions across three different restore points.

Comment: @JW0914: Yes, I know all that. SR used to have an XML file with the settings of folders and suffixes, but it's all hard-wired nowadays and opaque. Whatever you think of SR (I stopped arguing), don't trust it to result in a viable config, only use in energencies.